# Hide buttons when printing fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Fullcalendar on my site and I have a button to print it. I am doing this with:

```
function print_calendar() {
       $('#calendar').css('width', '6.5in');
    $('.fc-content .fc-state-highlight').css('background', '#ccc');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    bdhtml = window.document.body.innerHTML;
    sprnstr = "<!--startprint-->";
    eprnstr = "<!--endprint-->";
    prnhtml = bdhtml.substr(bdhtml.indexOf(sprnstr) + 17);
    prnhtml = prnhtml.substring(0, prnhtml.indexOf(eprnstr));
    window.document.body.innerHTML = prnhtml;
    window.print();
```

Now I also want to be able to hide the Previous Month, Next Month, Today, and Month Buttons. How can I do this via javascript? I do not want to change them in the fullcalendar code, just be able to hide them before printing but have them display the rest of the time.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?  You know of course that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, about as similar as ham is to hamster. You may want to lose the Java tag.

Comment: Never mind, I see that bemace has removed the Java tag from your question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use javascript for this, use a print-only style sheet (you don't even need a print button, the browser's print button will do fine):

```
@media print {
    input[type="button"] {
        display: none;
    }
    ...
}
```

or instead of wrapping in `@media print {}` you can put your print styles in a separate .css file and link with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." type="text/css" media="print">`.

Comment: Thankyou bemace, I understand your reason behind using a print css but I am actually doing some other things with the java call also so I would rather do this with java also

Comment: JavaScript is **not** the same as Java.  You'll confuse people if you try to use the names interchangably.  See my other answer for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you appear to be using jQuery, so if you must do this with javascript

```
$('button').css("display", "none")
```

or

```
$('input[type=button]').css("display", "none")
```

should work depending on how the buttons are defined.